# Not able to locate an element in protractor

Tags: node.js, protractor

I am having a UI as given below.

```
<div class="BtyD1c WFUbU" jsname="Y3PF3">
  <div>.........</div>
  <div>.........</div>
  <div>.........</div>
  <div>.........</div>
  <div>.........</div>
  <div jsname="YCbqLe" style="display: block;">
    <div>.........<div>
    <div class="qh jxzYFc ZlpBcf XWx4Gf IbyGtb Tea E5 OI LtchOd oj" jscontroller="pxq3x" jsaction="clickonly:KjsqPd; focus:Jt1EX; blur:fpfTEe; input:Lg5SV;" jsshadow jsname="NuJwOd">
       <div class="PI jh">
         <div class="D5 fda">
           <div class="F5">
             <input type="text" class="Ij Sl" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="off" tabindex="0" aria-label="Text input area where you can input a URL for the action." maxlength="1500" value="" autofocus="" data-initial-value="enter url here" badinput="false" dir="ltr" aria-invalid="false">
  </div>
  <div>.........</div>
```

I need to enter some input in this input field.For that i have used a locator

```
".Xz2Gac .WFUbU div:nth-child(6) .jxzYFc input"
```

But it says ElementNotVisibleError: element not interactable. But when i am giving the locators as

```
".Xz2Gac .WFUbU div:nth-child(7) .jxzYFc input"
```

then it is successfully entering the input data into that input field.I am not understanding why it so?because the input field is in 6th div of class 'WFUbU'.Am i right?.

Comment: have you tried `$("[aria-label='Text input area where you can input a URL for the action.']")`

Answer (score 0):

if you exam the html sample that you provided, you can see that there is 6 childs only.
For the css matcher, possibly it ignore the condition to find the 7 child (which does not exist) and continue with matching next case.

[image]

With the following experiment:

```
.WFUbU .jxzYFc input
```

you will get the input

```
.WFUbU div:nth-child(6) .jxzYFc input
```

you again get again the input

Here is full explanation about nth:child

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child

> Note: avoid creating such locators based on child of elements, due
>   dynamic changes of creation/updating a website.

If the unique jsname is always constat use something like:
CSS selector

```
input[jsname='YPqjbf']
```

Xpath selector

```
//input[@jsname='YPqjbf']
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.Actually there is one more div, after the div containing jsname="YCbqLe" as i shown above.So total 7 childs for the class WFUbU.The counting is start from 1.right? not from zero. right?

Comment: jsname='YPqjbf' is not unique. So i cannot use that also.

Comment: Based on your html sample if you paste it in browser, you can count (see) only 6 child(s) of .WFUbU class ... if you close all exposed div(s) probably will have 7 child.

Answer (score 0):

Try following two css locator manually in Chrome DevTool.

- `.Xz2Gac .WFUbU > div:nth-child(6) .jxzYFc input`
- `.Xz2Gac .WFUbU div:nth-child(6) .jxzYFc input`

If both locator find the same input, means there are one **invisible** input and one **visible** input.  You should use `.Xz2Gac .WFUbU div:nth-child(7) .jxzYFc input` to find the visible input.

If they find different input, I think `.Xz2Gac .WFUbU > div:nth-child(6) .jxzYFc input` should find the visible input that's what you want.

`>` in css locator means to fine direct/first layer child.

(blankspace) in css locator means to find descendants which includes direct/first layer child